# Using differentiation to find a power series representation.

Tags: calculus, power-series

For the first part, I have $$f(x)={1\over{(5+x)^2}}$$ but I have looked at my book and all over the internet and cannot find an example that is not in the form of $$f(x)={1\over{(1+x)^2}}$$ So I'm mostly wondering how that five changes everything. In the next part it asks me to use the information from above to find a power series for $$f(x)={1\over{(5+x)^3}}$$ and then one more time using the information, again, from what ever the power series of what I just wrote is: $$f(x)={x^2\over{(5+x)}^3}$$ Any ideas on how I should go about this? Thank you!

Comment: Factor the $5$ out. $\frac{1}{(5+x)^2}=\frac{1}{5^2} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x}{5}\right)^2}$.

Comment: substitute until you get something you recognize the series of. then substitute back.

Comment: Let's start with something you know for example $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ for $|x|<1$. What do you get when you differentiate it? Then you can make a substitution to get it in the form of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First using geometric series notice

$-\frac{1}{(5+x)}= \sum (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{5^{n+1}}$.

Now using the fact that the derivative of  $-\frac{1}{(5+x)}$ is $\frac{1}{(5+x)^2}$,
 simply differentiate the power series obtained for $-\frac{1}{(5+x)}$.

So you get
$\frac{1}{(5+x)^2}=\sum (-1)^{n+1}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{5^{n+1}}$